# Live Update CSS on input change with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create (or update?) CSS based on input value. In short, I have a color picker that's run from a text input field. When the input value changes (aka the color hex value), I need to update the css `background` on another element on my page with this value.

What I'm doing is not working. What am I doing wrong? Or what's the best way to update/replace CSS based on live input value?

Script:

```
    // Bar Background Color - Live Preview
    $('.bg_color').live("change", function() {

        var bg_color = $(this).val(); // grab color input value

        if ($(this).val().length > 0)
        {
            // replace css value on live preview 
            $('.campaignBar').css('background', bg_color);  
        } 
        else
        {
            //resorts back to default if no value entered
            $('.campaignBar').css('background', '#4575A1' });   
        }         

    });
```

Comment: What format is `bg_color` in?

Comment: If you're sure it's returning a value that contains the pound sign, you can try changing the line to `$('.campaignBar').css('backgroundColor', bg_color);`. Have you tried debugging with the console to make sure that that is the format that is being returned? Also, any errors? Oh, and FYI `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqE2R/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bg_color').miniColors({
    change: function(hex, rgba) {    
      if (hex.length > 0)
      {
       // replace css value on live preview 
       $('.campaignBar').css('backgroundColor', hex);  
      } 
      else
      {
        //resorts back to default if no value entered
        $('.campaignBar').css('backgroundColor', '#4575A1');   
      }         
     }
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: Okay, I had keyup before...but since i'm selecting the color from a color picker and no necessary writing it out, I can't use this. So my original code works if I manually type in the hex value, however when I select the code via the color picker, which most people will do, the live change doesn't happen. Any ideas? Here's the plug-in... https://github.com/claviska/jquery-miniColors/

Comment: Check my edits, there's a change callback for the minicolors, so just call it when you initialize the miniColors call for the text input

Comment: For some reason, this won't change the colours for me..!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me, maybe you need to post your entire js code and html so we can see more of what you're doing.

Comment: Okay, let me test this (Joshua was not the poster ;)). On first glace, shouldn't var bg_color point somewhere??

Comment: Sorry, removed that, its no longer needed with the change function, since hex is passed automatically.

Comment: Figured...works man!!!! Thanks so much!! Didn't notice the miniColors change function! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W54Yu/1/)**

```
$('.bg_color').on("change", function() {
    var bg_color = $(this).val(); 
    if (bg_color.length > 2)
    {
        $('.campaignBar').css("background-color",'#'+bg_color);
    } 
    else
    {
        $('.campaignBar').css('background-color','#4575A1');   
    }         
});​
```

I've set it to be greater than 2, as with a hex value you need to have 3 or more numbers for it to be recognised as a number.